# How can I sort an NSMutableArray containing NSDictionary's by numeric values?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

Essentially I have an `NSMutableArray` which contains several `NSDictionaries`. I wish to sort this array based on one of the numeric values that appears in each of the `NSDictionaries`.

For example, if these were all of the `NSDictionaries`:

```
dict_1
{
    some_val,         @"blah"
    some_other_val,   135
}

dict_2
{
    some_val,         @"blah"
    some_other_val,   10
}

dict_3
{
    some_val,         @"blah"
    some_other_val,   35
}
```

Then I want to sort them based on the value of `"some_other_val"`. I have attempted to do this using sort descriptors, however I presents me with the wrong results. Here is the code I use to sort the array:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"some_other_val" ascending:NO];
        [myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

As I mentioned, this does not provide the result I was expecting to see. Here are the results of the sort:

```
Before:
135
10
35

After:
35
135
10
```

As far as I can tell it's just trying to sort the values as if they are strings. I have had a look around online to see if I can find a solution to the problem however I'm at a bit of a dead end.

Please could someone offer some advice?

Comment: are you free to change the type for  "some_other_val"?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean, however I'm able to make changes to the NSDictionary if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that are several forms to do that, the first option:

I think that if you add some_other_val to the dictionary as NSNumber, you can get the result that you want, without change the rest.

I'll be looking for others.

Comment: user1118321 gave you another great tip, you can use a custom sorting function for perform the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use one of the other methods such as `sortUsingFunction:context:` or `sortUsingComparator`:?